# IF formula not working

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

What is wrong with this Excel formula?

`=IF((C7-$C$2)<=$C$2,(C7*C3),IF((AND((C7-$C$2)>(2*$C$2),(C7-$C$2)<=($C$2*2),((C7-$C$2)*($C$4)),IF(AND((C7-($C$2*2)>($C$2*2),(C7-$C$2)>($C$2*2),(C7-(C7-($C$2*2)),(C7*$C$5)))`

It's a sales calculation where:

- if you sell over a certain number you get one level of commission per deal and
- if you sell 2X a specific number you get a higher pay out for every deal

Comment: Write correct formula in math notation

Comment: Could you give some example with figures? You might have to restart the formula from scratch.

Answer (score 4):

I entered your formula into D7 and immediately got an error "The formula you typed contains an error" with the whole formula highlighted. That indicated that Excel couldn't find one explicit error. I also noticed that the last ")" wasn't black so that suggested a nesting error. My usual way for finding these is to F2 while on the cell and left arrow through the brackets - go over the last bracket and its corresponding bracket should turn bold in the cell/formula bar. If it's not the first bracket you've got a problem!

Bracketing can be good but it can be confusing if over-used - multiplications will always be calculated first by Excel before addition/subtraction so you could try getting rid of some bracket pairs **but read on because there may be a better solution**.

Formula are sometimes easier to understand if you define your parameters within **Named Ranges** (i.e. Base Sales Volume in C2 named as BSV or BaseSales) which you can then see in the formula. BaseSales is a lot easier to comprehend than $C$2.

After naming your ranges for the Base Sales, create **Named Ranges** for your three commission rates in $C$2, $C$3 and $C$4. Replace the references to the absolute cells in your formula. In 2007+ on the Formula tab go Define Name...Apply Name and highlight all the names you made then apply. Your formula should have names instead of cell references.

Nested formulae are good but sometimes you need to build them up from simple formulae over many columns and then consolidate the crucial bits to put into your mega-formula.

Instead of testing from the bottom up through the target levels consider top down - 
IF sales > top target
   sales * top rate
ELSE
   IF sales > 2nd target
      sales * 2nd rate
   ELSE
      sales * base rate

Then you should be able to do it with just two IF functions.

Comment: +1. Nice advices (did not know about defining names for cells and using it on formulas).